# How to create xml file using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am creating a xml file using Java Transformer.The root node has syntax like this:

```
<AUTO-RESPONSE-DOCUMENT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://someurl">.
```

I am creating the root node like this:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element ele = doc.createElement("AUTO-RESPONSE-DOCUMENT");
doc.appendChild(ele);
```

How should i put the above urls in front of AUTO-RESPONSE-DOCUMENT node?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the namespace attributes: You can set them like all other atributes:

```
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element ele = doc.createElement("AUTO-RESPONSE-DOCUMENT");

        //Add namespace attibutes
        ele.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        ele.setAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        ele.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://someurl");
        doc.appendChild(ele);
```

Put through this Document-To-Text code

```
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        //initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);
```

It creates that output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<AUTO-RESPONSE-DOCUMENT xmlns="http://someurl" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ParserConfigurationException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element ele = doc.createElement("AUTO-RESPONSE-DOCUMENT");
    doc.appendChild(ele);
    ele.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://someurl");
    ele.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    ele.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
}
```

Note the namespace for "xmlns" pefix must be exactly as shown.

Comment: Thanks for the approach.